# Здравствуйте. Проверьте пожалуйста правильность тестового задания

Tags: mysql, sql

В Базе данных есть 2 таблицы:

```
Sales (MonthId int, RTN int, sales_rub float)
```

```
Plans (MonthId int, RTN int, plan_rub float)
```

Где

- `MonthId`  - Id месяца, вида 202101, где первые 4 цифры год, 2 последних – номер месяца
- `RTN` – Id руководителя товарного направления (РТН)

**Написать скрипт**.
Который выведет сумму фактических продаж и плановых продаж по месяцам(MonthId) за 2021 год. При этом план может быть не по всем РТН, а продажи есть у всех РТН, по которым есть план.

**Решение**

```sql
SELECT s.Monthid,SUM(s.sales_rub), SUM(p.planes_rub) 
FROM sales AS s
LEFT JOIN Plans AS p ON s.Monthid = p.Monthid AND s.Rtn = p.Rtn
WHERE s.Monthid LIKE'2021%'
GROUP BY Monthid ;
```

**Заранее спасибо**

Comment: Если ориентироваться ТОЛЬКО на написанное условие - решение ошибочное.

Comment: @Akina. Можете подсказать в чем ошибка?

Comment: JOIN multiplying.

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее? Я только только начал изучать SQL

Comment: Какой в приведенных таблицах первичный ключ?

Comment: @Андрей, всё правильно. Я проверил

Comment: Само задание криво написано. Как будто плановые и фактические продажи нужно сложить вместе, а это явный бред.

Comment: @Akina Да вроде же всё нормально. Группировка есть. Если только само задание криво написано.

Comment: @CrazyElf *Да вроде же всё нормально.* Да вообще ничего не нормально. `GROUP BY Monthid` - угадай, из какой таблицы поле...

Comment: *А можно чуть поподробнее?* Если в таблице имеются дубликаты по выражению связывания, то SUM по другой таблице будет умножена на количество таких дубликатов.

Comment: @Akina А из какой таблицы будет поле в таком случае? Мне кажется, оно должно отругаться, что ему непонятна эта дуальность, не? )  А что касается дубликатов, мне кажется там нет дубликатов, запись максимум одна на каждое связывание, если она вообще есть.

Comment: @CrazyElf *Мне кажется, оно должно отругаться, что ему непонятна эта дуальность, не? )* Наивсенепременнейше. *что касается дубликатов, мне кажется там нет дубликатов,* С чего бы? не вижу никаких доказательств, что `(MonthId, RTN)` уникально в обоих таблицах, хотя и не исключаю такой возможности. Но даже если это выражение уникально - это не исключает дубликатов по одному полю `(MonthId)`, по которому выполняется группировка.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT s.Monthid, SUM( s.sales_rub ), SUM( p.planes_rub ) 
FROM sales AS s
LEFT JOIN Plans AS p ON s.Monthid = p.Monthid AND s.Rtn = p.Rtn
WHERE s.Monthid >= 202101 and s.Monthid <= 202112   
GROUP BY s.Monthid ;
```

Comment: а в mysql это норма проверять int like'ом?

Comment: действительно ) Неееееет !

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, исправил